# Encode a string in UTF-8

Tags: powershell, utf-8, encode

I want to encode a string into UTF8 in PowerShell.

This is what I tried:

```
$consumer_key ="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog"
$enc_consumer_key = System.Text.UTF8Encoding($consumer_key)
```

But I get an error:

> System.Text.UTF8Encoding in not recognize as the name of cmdlet

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$consumerkey ="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog"
$encconsumerkey= $enc.GetBytes($consumerkey)
```

Answer (score 16):

Encode/Decode:

```
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("â")
# 195 162
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($enc)
# â
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($enc)
# ??
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString($enc) # Windows-1252
# Ã¢
```

This is the best question I search that lead me to the above solution for text encoding/decoding characters in PowerShell.  In my case I was trying to debug malformed UTF8 characters.  Hope it helps someone in the future.

-Check that BOM

Comment: Where can I find the official document of this? In the document of .NET framework?

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to write the string to file:

```
$consumer_key ="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog"
$consumer_key |  Out-File c:\path\utf8file.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

$input = 'salut '
$output = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($input))
$output

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).