# Curl behaves inconsistently on Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, curl

I'm trying to write a Windows Powershell script but when I write `$ curl wttr.in` for example, I get the expected output however, when I do `$a=curl wttr.in;echo $a` I just get gibberish. I'm using the curl executable located in `C:\Windows\System32\` since I removed the default Powershell aliases related with `Invoke-WebRequest` (`curl` and `wget`). Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Here is what I mean:

### curl wttr.in (expected output)

[image: correct output]

### $a=curl wttr.in;echo $a (wrong output)

[image: wrong output]

Comment: I don't get either option unless I look at the `.Content` property of the curl result.

Comment: Also, upvote for showing me `wttr.in`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn are you sure you're using the curl executable located in `System32`? It seems you may be using Powershell's `Invoke-WebRequest`. Try doing `Get-Alias curl` and see if this is true.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with encoding. A workaround would be simply add `Out-String` when capturing

```
$a = C:\Windows\system32\curl.exe wttr.in | Out-String
$a
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't fix it for me. I keep getting the same output.

Answer (score 1):

I could not test it (response was "no more querys"), but you can force the output encoding into a specific encoding
[Encode a string in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256911/encode-a-string-in-utf-8)
may take some testing to find the right output.